# AngularJs Display a popover on click of progressbar

Tags: angularjs

I am looking to display a popover on click of progress bar , Is this something that can be accomplished without loading boostrap (additional js files?)

Looking to Add a simple title and description to popover on click. I am learning angularJs and trying to create a dummy project

Answer (score 0):

you need to use native JS onclick event and needs an html&css loaded in your index page.
you cant use angular ng-click and other directive before it get bootstrap.